# How can i fill a form from after clicking a commandbutton in JSF

Tags: forms, jsf-2

I have 2 text fields in which I take the user inputs and I use those to trigger a managedbean with an actionlistener from a button. This class will generate(from an xml) the data that I want to fill a datatable in different form in the same page. I could resolve this if the button would open a different page after the class was triggered but I don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the properties of the components of the other form accordingly in the bean action method.

E.g.

```html
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.input1}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{bean.input2}" />
    <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" rendered="#{not empty bean.items}">
        ...
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

with

```
private String input1;
private String input2;
private List<Item> items;

public void submit() {
    items = loadItBasedOn(input1, input2);
}
```

Comment: this is exacly my problem that the bean on the datatable is empty and it gets data from the bean.submit.

Comment: Blub? I do now not understand you anymore. That's exactly what my answer is showing. Please describe the concrete functional requirement clearly. Ask if necessary help to someone who's more proficient with English and/or web development to eliminate confusion caused by language barriers and/or wrong web development terminology.

Comment: Maybe is my English let me describe you again please, the 2 inputtext in the first form isn't actually inputtext but selectonelistbox. those selectonelistbox are getting there values from a class(let's say class1) that reads an XML, no problem so far. The values that the user selects from those selectonelistbox are 'saved' in other class (let's say class2). The method that the commandbutton triggers is the class2.submit which returns the list for the datatable in the second form.

Comment: Well, OK, I'm still unsure why my answer is unclear. It already shows how to do exactly that. Just set the properties for the other form in action method and return to the same page. If you want to have those properties in other bean instance, just inject that bean as managed property of the current bean. Or don't you even know at all how to do that and is that your *actual* problem?

Comment: well, i believe that on the last answer you answered me: "If you want to have those properties in other bean instance, just inject that bean as managed property of the current bean" as i told you i am new to this, thanks BalusC

Comment: Okay, you may then find [this blog](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html) helpful to get a refreshing introduction into some trivial but very important JSF communication basics, such as injecting managed beans in each other.